# how to import python 3 libraries in iron python

Tags: c#, python, .net, python-3.x, ironpython

I am trying to call a python script on a button click of an exe built with C#.

I installed the following dll's

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using IronPython.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting;
```

and myscript.py is

```
import sys
sys.path.append("C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib")
import os
print (os.getcwd())
import pandas as pd
print("hi")
```

my c# code:

```
 private static void doPython()
    {
        ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
        engine.ExecuteFile(@"test.py");
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

I get `unexpected token 'from'` error when running my solution, please help. thanks in advance

Comment: At which state do you get this error? I'd suggest to try to repro the issue with a simple `print("call success")` script first and take out functions one by one to track dwon the problem.

Comment: I tried with the sample printing line, I am getting error on 3rd `import os` line

Comment: I'd actually also put all the import statements first, before printing stuff or modifying paths

Comment: yes, If I put this import os on the first line I am getting the error at the very first line.

Comment: Which version of IronPython are you using? This sounds like a compatibility issue.

Comment: I see ironpython 2.7 is available in their site. is it compatible to run python3 scripts?? . Actually iron python exe is not installed in my machine, I am using `IronPython.Hosting`  and `Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting`  references, I raised a ticket for installing iron python, it will be installed today.